# Xamarin Picker selected item persisting on multiple pages

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.labs

**Question:**
Perhaps the challenge could be stated this way: How do I bind a single property in a content page to a globally stored variable in Xamarin Forms?

**Details:**
I am using the MVVM pattern. I have a navigation content page (1 of 3 such pages) with a Picker object which is populated dynamically from the collectionModel and said model is read/write. I am attempting to persist the SelectedItem (or index, whichever is most appropriate) thru all 3 content pages such that navigation from page to page shows the same item (from the user's perspective). How should I do this?

I can set the Picker.SelectedIndex manually in ContentPage_Appearing() event. I would much rather use binding.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please explain why in the comments and give me the chance to make the question better. I cannot think of a good reason to downvote this question which has received multiple votes in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a static class, like this:

   ```
   public static class DataClass
   {
      public static int PickerSelectedIndex = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Add the `xmlns:local` in `ContentPage` mark in each Content Page, like this:

   ```
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataPersist"
   ```
3. Binding the data for your controls in each page's Xaml, like this:

   ```
   <Picker  x:Name="picker" SelectedIndex="{x:Static local:DataClass.PickerSelectedIndex}">
   ```

It works like this:

[image]

Comment: Will be back on Xamarin dev in a few days and I'll mark this as the answer if it works. I'm thinking it should... I just didn't know about the x:Static thing and was confused at how I would bind to a different context / view model.

Comment: Here's the official documentation on `x:Static` :https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/#The_xStatic_Markup_Extension