# I am unable to get a Picker SelectedItem value on another page

Tags: xamarin, picker

I am trying to get a picker SelectedItem value for use on another page, but it doesn't seem to want to work. 
I found a "solution" here:[Xamarin Picker selected item persisting on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007802/xamarin-picker-selected-item-persisting-on-multiple-pages) but it doesn't want to work for me. When I try to use it, in say a label, I can't seem to get it to display. I can manually set the string, but not use the string of the actual selected item. 
I created the static class as directed:

```
public static class PickerPersist
{
    public static string pickerSelectedItem = "test";
}
```

and included the `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:C971"` and the label binding to `Text="{Binding x:static local:PickerPersist.PickerSelectedItem}"`and it correctly shows "test" when displaying the label.
My question is, how do I get the string of the actual SelectedItem to show? The Picker itself is on another page, and I was able to get it to display correctly with `var pickerItem = (Terms)termpicker.SelectedItem;`
I tried setting the `PickerSelectedItem` to `Page1.termPicker.SelectedItem;` but it comes back with the error "Page1.termPicker is inaccessible due to its protection level".
I was able to get rid of the error by setting `public static string Picked;` on the previous page class, and then setting the variable `pickerItem` to `Picked`. However, it doesn't seem to carry across to the new page. If I put a break after setting `pickeritem` to `Picked` everything shows that it is indeed set correctly, but it shows as null in the `PickerPersist` and thus not showing on the new page.

I hope all this makes sense.
Any help you can offer would be great!! Thanks!
Full code available here: https://github.com/yax51/C971.git

Xaml where Picker lives:

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:C971"
             x:Class="C971.Page1"
             Title="Term Selector">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Picker x:Name="termPicker" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TermName}"
                    Title="Select a term"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    SelectedItem="{x:Static local:PickerPersist.PickerSelectedItem}"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public static String Picked;
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    ...

        void TermGoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pickerItem = (Terms)termPicker.SelectedItem;


            if (pickerItem == null)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", "Please Select a term", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Picked = pickerItem.TermName;

                Navigation.PushAsync(new TermPage());
            }



        }
```

Static class

```
public static class PickerPersist
    {
        public static string PickerSelectedItem = Page1.Picked;
    }
```

Label on new page

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:C971"            
             x:Class="C971.TermPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="test" Text="{x:Static local:PickerPersist.PickerSelectedItem}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick Davis are you want to show selected Picker value on next page?

Comment: please post the relevant code here - linking to an external site is not recommended

Comment: @ChetanRawat Yes. I have tried several things. I tried setting PickerPersist class as not static, then using `PickerPersist pickerPersist = new PickerPersist();` on the new page and was able to successfully print it in a `Console.WriteLine`but unable to set it to the label text.

Comment: @Jason apologies. Question updated with relevant code.

Comment: Use Picker listener SelectedIndexChange, Create a view model update the property of view model when the selected item changed, and bind the text with label with view model property.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat Thanks! I think that worked. I was able to get the selectedItem to display in a Console.WriteLine, but nothing shows up on the label.
`Label Text="{Binding Pick}"` So it's being passed, but not showing anything.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat I figured it out. Needed to set a `<ViewCell>` and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Picker listener SelectedIndexChange, Create a view model update the property of view model when the selected item changed, and bind the text with label with view model property. – @Muhammad Adeel Shoukat

Did this and needed to add a ViewCell into the ListView and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.